# Sequelize Many to Many relationship issues

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to build a simple n:m relationship, the case is, one Doctor can have many Patients and a Patient can have many Doctors...

Doctor Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Doctor = sequelize.define('Doctor', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    doc_crm: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'doctors',
    timestamps: false
  })

  Doctor.associate = function (models) {
    Doctor.belongsToMany(models.Patient, { as: 'Patients', through: { model: models.PatientDoctor } })
    Doctor.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' })
  }

  return Doctor
}
```

Patient Model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Patient = sequelize.define('Patient', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'patients',
    timestamps: false
  })

  Patient.associate = function (models) {
    Patient.belongsToMany(models.Doctor, { as: 'Doctors', through: { model: models.PatientDoctor } })
    Patient.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'user_id' })
  }

  return Patient
}
```

And the joining table is

PatientDoctor

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const PatientDoctor = sequelize.define('PatientDoctor', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'patient_doctors',
    timestamps: false
  })
  return PatientDoctor
}
```

So, when i query the PatientDoctor model passing the Patient and Doctor i get a

```
{
    "name": "SequelizeEagerLoadingError"
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? i tried a lot of stuff, all without luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From a database design persective, your patientDoctor table might not be designed properly.  I would be leaning towards a composite primary key consisting of doctor and patient id's.

Comment: Please google many more specific, clear & concise titles/questions with tags & 'stackoverflow'. Have you even googled 'Sequelize Many to Many relationship stackoverflow'? And what does documentation suggest?

Comment: I've found the documentation less clear than optimal and different versions will behave weirdly.
- turning on verbose debug messages helps.
- which version numbers are you working with.
- are there any constraints in the database?